# Get characters after last / in url

Tags: php, string

I want to get the characters after the last / in an url like `http://www.vimeo.com/1234567`

How do I do with php?

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->afterLast('/')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L445) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Very simply:

```
$id = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
```

[strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) gets the position of the last occurrence of the slash; [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) returns everything after that position.

---

As mentioned by redanimalwar if there is no slash this doesn't work correctly since `strrpos` returns false. Here's a more robust version:

```
$pos = strrpos($url, '/');
$id = $pos === false ? $url : substr($url, $pos + 1);
```

Comment: This cuts of the first character if there is no slash at all.

Comment: @redanimalwar I added another solution

Comment: I am wondering why the `$str = basename($url)` is not getting more upvotes, works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @redanimalwar (1) basename is intended for file paths, not URLs - I think it will always return the same result but there may be edge cases like backslashes; (2) basename only works for slashes whereas my answer can be easily modified if someone else wants to do the same thing with a different character.

Answer (score 66):

Check out [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php). It should work like this:

```
$string = basename($url);
```

Comment: Does this work on urls? Isn't basename intended for file paths?

Comment: Seems to work fine, It's a string function; it doesn't check if the path exists.

Comment: Careful if you use this on strings other than URLs, e.g. classnames (__ CLASS __). basename() will work on Windows as the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is a backslash, but on Linux, basename() only looks for a slash, so basename('App\Class') will return "Class" on Windows but "App\Class" on Linux.

Answer (score 13):

You could [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) based on "/", and return the last entry:

```
print end( explode( "/", "http://www.vimeo.com/1234567" ) );
```

That's based on blowing the string apart, something that isn't necessary if you know the pattern of the string itself will not soon be changing. You could, alternatively, use a regular expression to locate that value at the end of the string:

```
$url = "http://www.vimeo.com/1234567";

if ( preg_match( "/\d+$/", $url, $matches ) ) {
    print $matches[0];
}
```

Comment: `explode` always seems like more overhead to me, though I haven't ever timed it to see how fast it is.

Comment: It appears explode() is  a bit slower. On 10k instances, this is the amount of time taken for both. substr() first: 0.013657/0.045038

Comment: Might be slower, but I prefer the explode here. Specifically if the url doesn't contain any "/" the +1 in the strrpos answer makes a mess explode is able to overcome.

Comment: The example throws a notice and should definetly be re-worked.

Comment: Yes, exploded data must be a variable

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`substr`](http://docs.php.net/substr) and [`strrchr`](http://docs.php.net/strrchr):

```
$url = 'http://www.vimeo.com/1234567';
$str = substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 1);
echo $str;      // Output: 1234567
```

Comment: More like this : ltrim(strrchr($url,"/"),"/"); strchr return a string, not a number

Answer (score 10):

```
$str = "http://www.vimeo.com/1234567";
$s = explode("/",$str);
print end($s);
```

Comment: my version, although the end result is the same as the one posted, enables OP to use the other items of the split up string if he wished to.

Comment: this is the correct answer, since the title asks after 'last' / in url

Answer (score 1):

`array_pop(explode("/", "http://vimeo.com/1234567"));` will return the last element of the example url

Comment: in php7 Returns notice: `PHP Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference`.

Answer (score 1):

My version is:

```
trim(strrchr($url, "/"), "/");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/function.strrchr

Answer (score 0):

Two one liners - I suspect the first one is faster but second one is prettier and unlike `end()` and `array_pop()`, you can pass the result of a function directly to `current()` without generating any notice or warning since it doesn't move the pointer or alter the array.

```
$var = 'http://www.vimeo.com/1234567';

// VERSION 1 - one liner simmilar to DisgruntledGoat's answer above
echo substr($a,(strrpos($var,'/') !== false ? strrpos($var,'/') + 1 : 0));

// VERSION 2 - explode, reverse the array, get the first index.
echo current(array_reverse(explode('/',$var)));
```

Comment: @redburn, Using `end()` this way in php 5.4+ and up will throw a notice. According to docs: "*you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array because only actual variables may be passed by reference.*".

Answer (score -1):

Here's a beautiful dynamic function I wrote to remove last part of url or path.

```
/**
 * remove the last directories
 *
 * @param $path the path
 * @param $level number of directories to remove
 *
 * @return string
 */
private function removeLastDir($path, $level)
{
    if(is_int($level) && $level > 0){
        $path = preg_replace('#\/[^/]*$#', '', $path);
        return $this->removeLastDir($path, (int) $level - 1);
    }
    return $path;
}
```