# Get last word from URL after a slash in PHP

Tags: php, url, get

I need to get the very last word from an URL. So for example I have the following URL:

http://www.mydomainname.com/m/groups/view/test

I need to get with PHP only "test", nothing else. I tried to use something like this:

```
$words = explode(' ', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$showword = trim($words[count($words) - 1], '/');
echo $showword;
```

It does not work for me. Can you help me please?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: What did it echo. Also why are you exploding the url between spaces, you should have explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

Answer (score 25, accepted):

by using regex:

```
preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", "http://www.mydomainname.com/m/groups/view/test", $matches);
$last_word = $matches[0]; // test
```

Answer (score 47):

Use [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) with parse_url:

```
echo basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this:

```
$lastWord = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
```

Thnx to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361752/4189000

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) but you need to use `/` as delimiter:

```
$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Note that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` can contain the query string if the current URI has one. In that case you should use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) before to only get the path:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

And to take trailing slashes into account, you can use [`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim) to remove them before splitting it into its segments using `explode`. So:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], '/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that you can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on your `REQUEST_URI`.I've made some simple function:

```
function getLast()
{
    $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

   # Remove query string
    $requestUri = trim(strstr($requestUri, '?', true), '/');
   # Note that delimeter is '/'
    $arr = explode('/', $requestUri);
    $count = count($arr);

    return $arr[$count - 1];
}

echo getLast();
```

Comment: Thanks everybody it works, but now I have another problem that I will explain in another post. Thanks

Comment: I see you're new here. Fell free to accept some answer here and vode some up/down. You can for example vote up all answers here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a query string being included when present, then just use `basename`. You don't need to use `parse_url` as well.

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomainname.com/m/groups/view/test';
$showword = basename($url);
echo htmlspecialchars($showword);
```

When the `$url` variable is generated from user input or from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`; before using `echo` use `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities`, otherwise users could add `html` tags or run `JavaScript` on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

use preg*

```
if ( preg_match( "~/(.*?)$~msi", $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ], $vv ))
 echo $vv[1];
else
 echo "Nothing here";
```

this was just idea of code. It can be rewriten in function.

PS. Generally i use **mod_rewrite** to handle this... ans process in php the $_GET variables.
And this is good practice, IMHO

Answer (score -2):

```
ex: $url      = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/ADU0QnQ4eDs';
$url      = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$basename = pathinfo($url_path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
// **output**: $basename is "ADU0QnQ4eDs"
```

complete solution you will get in the below link. i just found to Get last word from URL after a slash in PHP.

[Get last parameter of url in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257994/get-last-parameter-of-url-in-php)