# Get last word in URL and delete what is not necessary

Tags: php, url, get, request

Great guys have helped me a lot in this other post:

[Get last word from URL after a slash in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921075/get-last-word-from-url-after-a-slash-in-php)

Now I am facing another issue.

How can I say something like this in PHP:

if in `$last_word` you find also `-0.htm` then `delete -0.htm`

I explain my `$last_word` now shows `test-0.htm`

But I do not need `-0.htm`

I only need `"test"`.

How do I say in PHP to `delete -0.html` and to grab only `"test"`.

Thanks for your help. Since it is a dynamic script I obviously do not know what is before `"-0.html"`. The word "test" is only an example. Just to let you know that `"test"` is represented by a variable in my code, and it works. Now I only need to tell to the code to eliminate `0.html` when is found.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$last_word = str_replace(array('-0.html','-0.htm'), '', $last_word);
```

Hope this helps. It will replace the string (`-0.html` or `-0.htm`) even if found somewhere else than at the end of $last_word.

Comment: YES THATNKS IT WORKS. NOW I GOT YOUR POINTS, BOTH YOURS AND THE RUDIE'S ONE. SORRY GUYS, I AM NEW TO PHP. I KNOW I SEEMED IDIOT. I WAS JUST COMPLETELY CONFUSED.

Answer (score 1):

### Trying to remove `-0.htm` at the end of `$last_word`:

Regex is an easy way to go:

```
$last_word = preg_replace('/\-0\.htm$/', '', $last_word);
```

The `$` means 'the end', which means the `-0.htm` has be be at the end.

### If instead of `-0.htm` you want to remove `-0.html`:

```
$last_word = preg_replace('/\-0\.html$/', '', $last_word);
```

Comment: ok but how can I say to the code if -0.htm is found at the end?

Comment: @DiegoP: Both of these solutions will do that, just in different ways.

Comment: No wait. Maybe I have not explained it well. I need to say to the code that if in $last_word is found -0.htm at the end, then delete 0.htm and leave only "test". To grab "test" I used the function provided on the other post, that is: preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", "http://www.mydomainname.com/m/groups/view/test", $matches);
$last_word = $matches[0]; // test

Comment: Just to be clear I use a variable. The function I use is:preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
$last_word = $matches[0]; // test

Comment: You want `-0.html` removed from a string where it definitely not exists in?? That's strange... You say `"I need to say to the code that if in $last_word is found -0.htm at the end, then delete 0.htm and leave only "test""` which is exactly what my answer does =)

Comment: Ok I will try to explain as better as I can. I use this function: preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
$last_word = $matches[0]; // test  . This function in some cases gives http://www.iamassyrian.com/m/groups/view/test , in some other cases it gives http://www.iamassyrian.com/m/groups/view/test-0.htm. So I have to say to the code that if you find -0.htm, then delete 0.htm and give me only http://www.iamassyrian.com/m/groups/view/test. But "test" is the result of a variable, this is why I do not know to say to the code "if you find -0.htm after that variable =((

Comment: I understand how you get `$last_word`. The problem is that sometimes `$last_word` contains `"-0.html"`, right? So you want that removed? That's what the codes in my answer do. **edit** Just try it and see if it is what you mean =)

Comment: Wow... You have now explained the same thing four times and four times everybody understood and verified to you that my answer does exactly what you want. What else do you need???

Comment: ok WAIT. Maybe I found a good way to explain. This is the logic of the code. If in $last_word you find 0.htm, then delete 0.htm and leave all the rest. Is this clear now? How do I achieve this? I am confused.

Comment: Yeah so am I. I'm also annoyed. I wanna use caps, but I won't =) **Please** try out my answer. It'll do exactly as you want. How can you not understand that I understand what you mean? It's not so hard... If the last part of `$last_word` is `-0.htm`, remove it!

Comment: I've updated `$url` to `$last_word` in my answer. Do you get it now?

Comment: Ok Maybe I am an idiot. This is what I am doing preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
$last_word = $matches[0]; // test
$last_word = preg_replace('/\-0\.htm$/', '', $last_word);
$last_word = substr($last_word, 0, -6);  This is completely deleting "test" and it is leaving only -0.htm. This is doing exactly the opposite of what I am trying to achieve. Then I have to say to the code "if -0.htm is found", because -0.htm it's not ALWAYS there. Only when is found must be deleted.

Comment: Rudie. Really you are GREAT. I understand your point. Completely. And it works fine if it was what I am looking for. But this is not what I am looking for so far. I mean I need a function that will say "if in $last_word you find -0.htm, then delete -0.htm". You have provided the function to correctly delete -0.htm. What is missing is "if is found", because if I do not give an if, the function you have provided will delete 6 characters even if when -0.htm it's not there. Do you know how can I say "if -0.htm is in the variable $last_word then delete it?"

Comment: **OMG this is not worth it**. I give up. Just use Tadeck's answer.