# Get the value of a URL after the last slash

Tags: php

Say I have the following URL values:

```
http://website.com/tagged/news/
http://website.com/tagged/news
http://www.website.com/tagged/news/
http://www.website.com/tagged/news
```

I'd like to have a PHP function to get news in this example. So I want the value after the last slash if it isn't blank and if that value is blank, then I'd like to get the value before that slash.

I found this post:
[Get last word from URL after a slash in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921075/get-last-word-from-url-after-a-slash-in-php)

But I'd like to be really sure just in case someone types a slash at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As easy as:

```
substr(strrchr(rtrim($url, '/'), '/'), 1)
```

Comment: or the slower end(explode("/",$url)) but +1 cause yours is faster

Comment: @nathan hayfield: `end(explode("/",$url))` shouldn't be used, it accepts a reference, not an expression

Comment: @nathan hayfield: it generates warning

Comment: @nathan hayfield: it has nothing to do with php as a language :-)

Comment: @zerkms Oh no it doesn't. My bad. Tested and validated. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `basename($url)`

Answer (score 1):

A little more verbose, but something like this should work:

```
$url = ... //your url
//trim slashes off the end to make sure url doesn't end with slash
$results = explode('/', trim($url,'/'));
if(count($results) > 0){
    //get the last record
    $last = $results[count($results) - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try preg_match()

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php and http://www.regular-expressions.info/