# Getting value from url between forward slashes

Tags: php, regex

Getting the value from url which is between the forward slashes. Like

`http://localhost/test/manage-users/1230/`

output: `1230`

I also found some help full answers but they are not satisfy my case properly. Their url is hard coded i.e, their url cant change but in my case url change if user redirect from different pages.

[Get the value of a URL after the last slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076263/get-the-value-of-a-url-after-the-last-slash)

Different url when user redirect from different pages.

1. `http://localhost/test/manage-users/1230/?value=1230`
2. `http://localhost/test/manage-users/1230/`
3. `http://localhost/test/manage-users/1230/test1/?value=1230`

So i want a `regex` which full fill my all cases.

Comment: Generally you should post any attempts you have made so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RegEx** you need is

```
\d+(?=\/)

$re = '/\d+(?=\/)/'; 
$str = 'http://localhost/test/manage-users/1230/?value=1230'; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

It is working for all three cases you have mentioned.

[Check Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sI6dK9)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to get the number between slashes,

```
\/(\d+)\/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nA3lI3)

Your php code would be,

```
<?php
$re = '~\/(\d+)\/~'; 
$str = 'http://localhost/test/manage-users/1230/?value=1230'; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
?> // 1230
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible or not but i have a suggestion. Use URL rewriting.

Feel free to shape your URL's. For example

```
http://localhost/test/manage-users.php?value=1230
```

And a little help from this link:
http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

You can make it look like:

```
http://localhost/test/manage-users/1230/
```