# Get last parameter from the URL

Tags: php

I want to get the **last** parameter from the following type of structure:

```
$current_url = "/wp/author/admin/1";
```

So, from above url I will like to get "1"

The following code will return it correctly, but here I'm specifying the exact position of the variable. How can I get the last parameter without specifying its position (eg. no matter how many parameters are in the URL, just get the last one):

```
$parts = explode('/', $current_url);
var_dump($parts[4]);
```

Comment: There are a few different approaches for this. Here are a [few suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921075/get-last-word-from-url-after-a-slash-in-php) to a similar question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a regular expression for this, as you can do quite a few nice things, e.g. also allow URLs that end in `/`:

```
if (!preg_match('/\/([^\/]*)\/?$/', $current_url, $matches)
    // do something if the URL does not match the pattern
$lastComponent = $matches[1];
```

**What's happening here?** The regular expression matches if it can find a forward slash (the `\/`) followed by any number of characters that are not slashes (the `([^\/]*)`), which may then optionally be followed by another slash (the `\/?`), and then arrives at the end of the string (the `$`).

The function returns a value that evaluates to false if the regular expression did not match, so you are prepared for garbage input and may emit a warning if appropriate. Notice the parentheses in `([^\/]*)`, which will take all the characters mathced here (everything from the slash to the end of the input string or the last slash), and put it into its own match (`$matches[1]`).

I recommend you try [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/) if you want to debug and check your regular expressions. They are very powerful tools and quite underused in programming. Especially in PHP, where you get nice functions for them (e.g. `preg_match`, `preg_match_all`, and `preg_match_split`).

Answer (score 0):

after you explode the array use the end() function. That will always grab the last element in the array.

https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.end.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other methods, I would use `array_pop`

```
$parts = explode('/', $current_url);
var_dump(array_pop($parts));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php
"array_pop() pops and returns the last value of the array, **shortening the array by one element.**"

but the last note is important as it affects the contents of $parts array

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = explode("/", $url);
echo end($parts);
```