# Have app.yaml convert directory path to php script parameter

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

Is it possible to have navigating to...

```
https://website.com/photos
```

...be the same as navigating to...

```
https://website.com/index.php?action=displayPhotos
```

...?

---

I have tried variations of the following without success...

```
- url: /photos
  script: /index.php?action=photos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left app.yaml as it was...

```
- url: /(.+)
  script: index.php
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: index.php  
  secure: always
```

...and used PHP to read from the URL.

```
$directory = basename(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH));
if ($directory !== "" && $directory !== "index.php") {
    $action = $directory;
}
elseif (isset($_REQUEST["action"])) {
    $action = $_REQUEST["action"];
}
else {
    $action = "(unspecified)";
}
```

This facilitates script.js utilizing the less attractive form for passing one or more parameters, while site visitors can simply use slash plus text to indicate a single action or request.

---

Credit to [sanjary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5921179/199374) to another question for reading the URL after the slash.