# Get the last part of a URL using Php

Tags: php, string

Using, PHP I want to get the last part of url (i.e. the part after the last slash).

So,

From:

`http://scta.info/resource/person/Aristotle`

I would like to just get

`Aristotle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$link = 'http://scta.info/resource/person/Aristotle';
$myarray = explode('/',$link);
echo end($myarray);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a great answer. Not sure why my question got two down votes. Seems like a straight forward question with a straightforward answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, Ram, I have to wait ten more minutes before I can accept it.

Comment: @Jeff it is a straightforwarded question. And that's why it's downvoted. There are questions regarding this subject already

Comment: @Jeff [Just a quick example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361741/get-characters-after-last-in-url?rq=1)

Comment: @Déjàvu, if you know anything than it doesn't mean to vote down other. if the question is irrelevant than it's understandable.

Comment: @RamSharma I didn't downvote him. I'm just saying that there are other questions like that on this site and people might've downvoted him for that.

Comment: @RamSharma But if the question "doesn't show any research effort", it's candidate to downvote. If I search "get the last part of a url php" in google, the 3 first results are **exact** duplicates to this question ...

Comment: In that case put the question on hold or mark it as duplicate that's it.