# Get End Part of URL Before Trailing Slash

Tags: php

I'm attempting to retrieve the last part of a URL before the trailing backslash. I have used this previously, which worked great, but the URL on the site I was developing back then did not have a trailing slash. Below is the code I used for that.

```
$link = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$link_array = explode('/',$link);
echo $page = end($link_array);
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Kind Regards,

Rees

Comment: any example of your URL ?

Comment: are you asking this http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: $link = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

This retreives the URL, so anything with a trailing slash, there is 3000+ pages, hence the request uri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
$link = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if(substr($link, -1) == '/') {
$link = substr($link, 0, -1);
}
$link_array = explode('/',$link);
echo $page = strtoupper(end($link_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try :

```
$link = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$link_array = explode('/',$link);
$lastPart = str_replace('/', '', $link_array[count($link_array) - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You have to pick the second last value:

```
$link = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$link_array = explode('/',$link);
end($link_array);//move cursor to the end
//pick last or second last depending on trailing slash
$page = substr($link,-1) == "/" ? prev($link_array) : current($link_array);
echo $page;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use php's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to parse the url and get the wanted components.

or

**EDIT:**

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
if (substr("url", -1) == '/') {
    rtrim($url , "/")
}
$lastPart = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
```

This is from Stackoverflow posts:

[Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

[Get characters after last / in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361741/get-characters-after-last-in-url)

Comment: We didn't fully understand what part of the url you wanted.
For example the url: www.example.com/a/b/c/d.php :
Do you need "d.php" or "a/b/c/d.php".

Comment: example.com/one/two/

This would be the structure, and I would want two, without the trailing backslash

@yanivel