# how to get value from url in php

Tags: php, html

Not like as we get id from URL using `?id=value` and using  `$GET`.

i have a URL like below:

```
https://localhost/booktheparty/index.php?/hyderabad/corporate-party-planner/view-corporate-entertainment-activities/ENT105012/50/12
```

i cant edit the url because the last parameters are coming from database.

i need to get the value "12" which is present at the very end of the URL. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And if you don't want an answer in SQL, then remove the tag.

Comment: you need to research PHP / htaccess URL rewriting.

Comment: There are various ways. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361741/get-characters-after-last-in-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regular expression`

```
$url='https://localhost/booktheparty/index.php?/hyderabad/corporate-party-planner/view-corporate-entertainment-activities/ENT105012/50/12';
preg_match("/\/(\d+)$/",$url,$matches);
$lastParams = $matches[1];
```

You can pass this variable in another page using query string for example

```
header('Location: http://www.ccm.net/forum/?var='.$lastParams);
```

and use `$_GET['var']` on that page to get the value

Comment: getting it, but no able to pass it to another page

Comment: @ZubairShah you can assign this value to any other variable and use that variable in the url to redirect OR you can use session

Comment: how is that? can you please tell me so i can complete my work and accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode.

```
$url_exp =  explode("/", $url);
$lastValu = end($url_exp);
```

Comment: how do i add my current url, the $url value

Comment: you can get the same using `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you would use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(url, '/', -1) as last_part
```

Comment: @how do i use it in php