# How to get specific information from a url?

Tags: javascript

I would like to take only the part using javascript

```
cdf28fbc167d0fa6bdbf2928f1a18235a5d2ab24659455f0108dc3bcdcbe5608
```

from the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/resetPassword/cdf28fbc167d0fa6bdbf2928f1a18235a5d2ab24650855cbe01c6b01
```

How can I do it?

I tried to use location but without success

Comment: `window.location.pathname.match(/resetPassword\/([^/]+)/)?.[1]` is one way to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get characters after last / in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361741/get-characters-after-last-in-url)

Comment: `location.pathname.split("/").at(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

It can be achived by using `lastIndexOf` and `substring`:

```js
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/resetPassword/cdf28fbc167d0fa6bdbf2928f1a18235a5d2ab24650855cbe01c6b01'

console.log(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const url = "http://localhost:3000/resetPassword/cdf28fbc167d0fa6bdbf2928f1a18235a5d2ab24650855cbe01c6b01";

console.log(url.split("/")[4])
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
window.location.href.split("/").slice(-1)[0]
```